# Blender settings and Windows drivers for OpenCL rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

I recently got a Radeon RX Vega 64, first time AMD GPU user, so I'm not quite sure how to set Blender up for it and/or the drivers I'll have to have installed in order for it to work correctly.

So far the performance has been quite erratic while on GPU rendering (on CPU it works fine). A lot of crashing.

**1 -** Apart from selecting my Video Card as a Cycles Compute Device I wanted to know if there is anything else I should make sure to set up within Blender.

**2 -** Also, and maybe more important, what kind of Windows drivers do I have to install for it to perform properly? I'm not familiarized with AMD drivers.

All information I find specifically for Blender, addresses problems pre-2.79.

Thank you.

Comment: I've done this. I'm used to working with Nvidia GPUs, so I know the basic settings. I'd like to know specifics for AMD. I know nothing about drivers for those for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to http://support.amd.com and download the latest driver. You cant do much wrong. Other then that, there's no special setup needed.

Also: As you can see [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles#OpenCL), the OpenCL/AMD support in Blender got a huge leap with 2.79.